Floating Labels (Etiquetas flotantes) no se quedan suspendidas al tener texto
Estoy desarrollando un login con etiquetas flotantes, y funcionan. Pero a la hora de desenfocar el input se devuelven a su punto original, tenga o no tenga texto. Quiero que se mantenga suspendido en el aire mientras el input sea invalido o tenga texto en él. Ya le he agregado los eventos correspondientes pero no consigo el cometido. El login lo estoy haciendo con react y css puro.
Dejo el código por aquí.
Componente
const LoginForm = () => {
  return (
    <div className="login-container">
      <div className="login-background">
        <LogoContainer name={"Hola de nuevo"} />
        <form className="login-form">
          <div className="entry-area">
            <input id="username" type="text" className="input-control" placeholder=" "/>
            <label htmlFor="username" className="floating-label">
              Usuario/Correo electrónico
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="entry-area">
            <input
              type="password"
              name=""
              placeholder=" "
              id="password"
              className="input-control"
            />
            <label htmlFor="password" className="floating-label">
              Contraseña
            </label>
          </div>
          <a href="">Recuperar contraseña</a>
          <div className="actions">
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-light">
              Iniciar sesión
            </button>
            <button className="btn btn-outline-light">Registrarme</button>
          </div>
          <p className="error-link">
            ¿Hubo algún error? Informa <a href="">aquí</a>
          </p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

Estilos
.entry-area {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.floating-label {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: transform 100ms ease;
  color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  top: -10px;
}

.input-control {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transition: border-color 100ms ease;
}

.input-control:focus {
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}


.input-control:focus + .floating-label,
.input-control:not(:placeholder-shown) + .floating-label {
  transform: translate(-12%, -10px) scale(0.75); /* Reducir el tamaño cuando se enfoca */
}

.input-control:not(:focus):not(:placeholder-shown) + .floating-label {
  transform: translateY(10px);  
}


Ignorar:
React, JS, TSX, CSS, HTML
